# Where can I find my mySQL database (using locate doesn't help)?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, sqlite, ubuntu

First ever Stack Overflow post, thanks for your time. Any constructive criticism on how to post better, please just let me know. I have done a search on my query and have found similar posts, but I was unable to use the information within them to resolve my problem.

I have created a mysql database using the terminal window in my Ubuntu system (which I am also new to, having been a lifelong windows user). I used the following code in the terminal window:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Then once in mysql, I did the following

```
CREATE DATABASE securities_master;
USE securities_master;
```

I created a user and tables in the database using some other code, that doesn't seem relevant here, so I won't bother posting. However, I then decided I would like to take a look at the tables in the database, so I downloaded an SQLite browser. It was at this point that I realized I could not find my database file.

I tried to find the answer on previous stack overflow posts, and tried the suggestions of:

```
locate sqlite
locate .db
locate .sqlite
locate securities_master
```

But unfortunately, none of these showed the file I was looking for. The only place I can think of would be what is called the 'root' directory in my computer, but the Ubuntu file manager system won't let me view it because it says I don't have permissions. Is this where it might be?

Could someone shed some light on where I might be able to find this file/database? I know it is definitely there because if I try to CREATE it again, I get the message that it can't because it already exists.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite and mysql are two different databases. You can't use sqlite on a mysql database. sqlite is a single-file database, in which users just open the file and read and write to it, while mysql is a more traditional relational database system with a server and a client, where the server manages the database (which is generally in a directory of files), while the client just connects to the server.

Where the mysql database is located my depend on your system, but it's usually in `/var/lib/mysql`. You can look in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` for the configuration file, which should have a `datadir` option that refers to where the actual data for the database is stored.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your response, I found it very helpful. I tried to upvote it, but apparently because I have a reputation less than 15, this doesn't change the publicly viewed score.

The clarification on the difference between mysql and sqlite is understood now. I am a total newbie to relational databases, so this was helpful.

I eventually found the file in `/var/lib/mysql` as you advised. The reason it was not showing up when using `locate` in terminal window is that I did not have permissions to the `mysql` folder. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my.ini file to see where the data folder is located.

Usually there is a folder {mysqlDirectory}/data

MySQL data storage:

```
Commands.frm
Commands.myd
Commands.myi
```

The *.frm files contain the table definitions. Your *.myi files are MyISAM index files. Your *.myd files contain the table data.

Comment: Thank you Shivam. I eventually found the files in `/var/lib/mysql` the issue was that I didn't have permissions to that folder. Many thanks for the explanation of what the file extensions mean.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the answer before mine, mysql and sqlite are two different systems.

You mention you used the cmd line mysql to create the database and then wanted to view the tables. If you're simply trying to see which table are created, in the same command line you used to Create the database you can run `show tables;`

If you're after a GUI for this, we'd need a bit more context. Is this ubuntu system a remote server, or are you using the desktop version? 
You say you're a long time windows user, If you're using windows locally, I personally like SQLWorkbench for accessing my remote mysql servers.

EDIT: I just re-read your post and realised you're using local ubuntu desktop so me mentioning remote was silly, my bad!  However, SQLWorkbench does have a ubuntu version at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Thank you Jed. As mentioned on my reply to @Brian Campbell, I was unable to upvote your reply, but I am grateful for it. Yes, I was after a GUI and based on your advice I have downloaded SQL Workbench. I tried to use `show tables;` as advised but I think by changing my permissions to the `/var/lib/mysql` folder, I have now shot myself in the foot, as  I get `mysql> USE securities_master
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'securities_master'`

I will try to work out what I need to do to get back to being able to access this database. Thank you for taking the time to respond to me.